# Google Maps Api is not recognizing/working if change package ID but old package ID work -Android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google map API is not working when I change project package ID. its don't load map but old package ID work and load map.
**I had tried these solutions also but still not working:**
  1-Filter with 'Google Maps' in your logcat.
  2-You will see an error message, which contains the correct package name & SHA key which should be 
  present as it is in the API Key
  3-Go to Google Cloud Console -> API -> Credentials, and cross-verify both the above, correct if 
  necessary.
  Wait for 10-15 minutes for the API Key changes to be reflected

**Here is the Layout:**

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Here is the Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.lagoontechnologies.fclimousine">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainNagActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.MapViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
 </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Finally, I made it.**

Steps to fix were:
1)I've uninstalled the application from my device 
2)Deleted app-debug.apk, app-debug-unaligned.apk from android/app/build/outputs/apk 
3)Deleted API Key from Google Developer Console 
4)Generated new API key 
5)Added new Key to in AndroidManifest.xml 
6)Built my app on the device